# setting up fcgi and suexec in apache debian setup

Tags: apache-http-server

I've been trying to setup fcgi and suexec in my apache server.

I've read these articles

http://blog.koenreiniers.nl/guide-to-combining-apache-virtual-hosts-and-php7-fpm/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal

I've manage to setup half way but still getting Error 500 Internal server error.

Here is my fastcgi-custom.conf, which apply global configuration

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Here is my sites-available/website.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php7-fcgi-myuser .php
    Action php7-fcgi-myuser/php7-fcgi-myuser
    Alias /php7-fcgi-myuser /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.fcgi -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.mysuser.sock -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler php7-fcgi-myuser
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

my pool user file is

/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/myuser.conf

```
[myuser]
user = myuser
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.myuser.sock
```

As for the example,
http://blog.koenreiniers.nl/guide-to-combining-apache-virtual-hosts-and-php7-fpm/

there is no file for /run/php/php7.0-fpm.myuser.sock

I have following errors in my log file

```
[fastcgi:error] [pid 2141] [client 103.21.172.30:35622] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.fcgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec), referer: https://mydomain.co.nz/

[fastcgi:error] [pid 2141] [client 103.21.172.30:35622] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.fcgi", referer: https://mydomain.co.nz/
```

Any help would be appreciated

Also if anyone knows a fCGI documentation please let me know

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if this question would be better answered at Server Fault. I've flagged it for transfer.

Comment: Yes that's fine. Do i have to write it or can this question need some transfer ?